# In Scheme or Racket when to use functions and when to use macros

Tags: scheme, racket

Can someone give some general guidelines about when to use Scheme or Racket macros and when to use functions.

If you're not creating new syntax and you're not creating side effects on variables are there cases where you would either have to (or it would be more appropriate) to use macros instead of functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Macros allow you to use completely different syntax.** A macro invocation doesn't have to look like a function call at all, although the simplest macros often do. Also, **macros are performed in a separate phase before runtime**. So, if you need different syntax, or if you want macro expansion before runtime, then, well, use a macro.

In general, I'd say that if you can do it cleanly with a function, then use a function.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your very clear explanation.  But what I'm really wondering about is if you are not creating new syntax and you are not creating side effects on variables (such as simulating call by reference etc.) are there cases were a macro can accomplish something a function can't or do it better?

Comment: Another way to look at it: macros let you decide on what kinds of computation should happen at compile-time vs run-time.  Compile-time computation usually deals with syntactic issues.  But some programs crucially depend on compile-time computations, such as the type-checking phase of a typed language like Typed Racket.  Most programmers don't need to do significant compile-time computation, so stick with plain vanilla functions unless you really need to express computation at compile-time.

Answer (score 4):

[Matthias Felleisen](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/) has a brief discussion of this question in his [Racket style guide](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/Style/style/Choosing_the_Right_Construct.html#%28part._.Functions_vs_.Macros%29).

Comment: Thanks Sam.  I noticed his brief comments, but I also noticed in his todo list at the end of the style guide he asks for someone to write a whole section on this question for the guide so I assumed that it was a more involved than those brief comments of his.